# Problem to find the right JIRA Java SDK version

Tags: java, jira-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

[1] I am having a hard time finding the right JIRA SDK version. I want this `StatusCategory` class, but I do not find the right jar file containing it.

https://docs.atlassian.com/DAC/javadoc/jira/reference/com/atlassian/jira/issue/status/category/StatusCategory.html

[2] I downloaded the Atlassian JIRA SDK according to their description, but I do not find the jar file in there. Maybe I looked wrong?

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1210950/atlassian-plugin-sdk-windows/version-history

[3] I also tried to find the JAR file using `mvnrespository.com`, but no luck, all dependencies are scoped with `provided`.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-api

[4] Previously, I used an old version of the JIRA API, which worked, but it does not contain the `StatusCategory` class, which I want.

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.atlassian.fugue/fugue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
            <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Am I the only person who finds this whole JIRA Java SDK thing kind of messy ;-)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by going down the route [2].

You create a JIRA plugin using their archetype generator by invoking `atlas-create-jira-plugin.bat`.

Let `/` be the installation folder of the JIRA SDK. You use the settings.xml in `/apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/settings.xml` and use `/repository` as your m2 repository. You can override these settings per-project in IntelliJ.